# fetch value from a string quoted json in shell script

Tags: shell, packer

manifest.json will have below content

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "name": "golden-image",
      "builder_type": "amazon-ebs",
      "build_time": 1689613460,
      "files": null,
      "artifact_id": "us-east-1:ami-1234567890abc,us-west-2:ami-0987654321abc”,
      "packer_run_uuid": “test-uuid”,
      "custom_data": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I can fetch the value of artifact_id by running below command :

```
export AMI_ID=$(cat manifest.json| jq -r '.builds[0].artifact_id')
```

AMI_ID will have the value in string "us-east-1:ami-1234567890abc,us-west-2:ami-0987654321abc”

Now, I wanted to get the value of only us-east-1 using shell, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the given region AMI ID from below commands

```
region=${us-east-1}
export AMI_ID=${${$(cat manifest.json| jq -r '.builds[0].artifact_id')#*$region:}%*,*}
```